# Hiding Androids Media Control Notifications

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, mobile

I have implemented a video using HTML5 on a website, which contains no sound and functions as a background video loop. If a user visits that site on chrome mobile on Android, media controls for the video appear in their notification bar. I don't need these controls for the site and want to ask if it's possible to hide these media-control-elements using JavaScript.

What I mean with "media-control-elements" shows the following [example](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/media-notifications).